# beginner c++: why does this code give different results?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner trying to write something in c++. In the code below i get one result if i enter 56 for 'adig', and then another result if i still enter 56, but remove the comment marks from the 2 lines they are on in the code below (so that they are part of the code and no longer comments), and instead comment `cout << sumodd(adig)` (so that it's not part of the code).

why am i getting 2 different results?

Thnx

```
int sumodd( char adig1)

{
  int actualnum = adig1 - '0';
  return(actualnum);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  char adig;
  cout << "Enter a number\n"; 
  adig = cin.get();

  cout << sumodd(adig);
  //sumodd(adig);
  //cout << sumodd;

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: You can't enter 56 for `adig` using `cin.get()`. Only the 5 will be consumed. The 6 will remain in the input buffer for the next input operation.

Comment: What does  `adig1 - '0'` do ? I'm trying to understand, i don't get it.

Comment: @LolWalid: Subtracts the numeric value of the character `'0'` (48 in the case of the most widely used character sets) from `adig1`. If `adig1` is itself a digit character, the result is that digit's numeric value. i.e., '0' becomes 0, '1' becomes 1, '2' becomes 2, etc...

Comment: @LolWalid: Look at an ASCII chart to see the decimal value for `0`, and then do the math to see what the ASCII value for '5' - ASCII value for '0' would produce. (Spoiler alert: It converts an ASCII character for a digit to an actual numeric value.)

Answer (score 1):

```
sumodd(adig);
cout<<sumodd;
```

With this code, you´re calling sumodd without saving the result,
and then you´re printing the address of the function sumodd.
If you don´t like the one-liner, maybe you want something like

```
int res = sumodd(adig);
cout<<res;
```

Comment: PS: Don´t use `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])`, even if VS generates it. Just `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`, or `int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])` for ITF16, is fine.

Comment: *"...then you´re printing the address of the function `sumodd`."* - not actually printing the address, as `std::cout` doesn't have a suitable overload, and the address undergoes standard conversion to the `bool` `true`, meaning `1` is printed by default.